# Compose Desktop composable names starts with lowercase

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

as you all may know a `Composable` function names in Jetpack Compose should start with Uppercase.
but in `Compose Desktop` editor shows warning when I use Uppercase letter for my `Composable` first letter!

`Function name 'App' should start with a lowercase letter`

I want to just copy and paste lots of code from `Android` in my project.

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to install additional plugins in your IDE to resolve this lint error. Check to see whether you have the Compose Multiplatform IDE Support plugin installed for Android Studio/IntelliJ.

[image: Compose Multiplatform IDE Support Plugin]

[image: No lint error]